# Is there a way to stop WYSISYG editor in wordpress from trimming out certain tags?

Tags: wordpress

I'm sick of this WYSISYG editor of wordpress. Every time I switch from HTML view to WYSISYG view & back, it trims out many tags.  is one such tag. I know I can force wordpress to disable WYSISYG editor, but is there any way/patch to ask WYSISYG editor not to trim out tags.

Comment: Looks like the SO-editor strips out your tags too. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

One thing to look at is in the Writing settings, uncheck "WordPress should correct invalidly nested XHTML automatically" It may not fix it all, but it does take care of some of them.